# Unable to delay execution of funcRemove

Tags: javascript, event-handling, alert

I'm having an issue with delaying the execution of `funcRemove` till after the `alert` fires.

I tried using `setTimeout` but then I keep getting an error stating that the `remove` property doesn't exist. How do I accomplish delaying the execution of `funcRemove` till after the `alert` fires?

const listAddCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const moveElem = document.querySelector('.moves');

```
let turnCheck = 0;
let cardChecker = '';
let prevCard = '';
let moves = 3;

let matchCheck = function(evtObj){
  funcShow(evtObj);  
  console.log(turnCheck);
     if(turnCheck===1){
        setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
        if(evtObj.target.innerHTML===cardChecker){
            evtObj.target.classList.add('match');
            prevCard.classList.add('match');
        }
        else{

            alert('No match');
        }
        funcRemove(prevCard, evtObj);
        turnCheck = 0;
        cardChecker = '';
        prevCard = '';
        moves++;
        moveElem.innerHTML = moves;
        return;
     }
     prevCard = evtObj.target;
     cardChecker = evtObj.target.innerHTML;
     turnCheck++;
 }

 let funcShow = function(e){
    e.target.classList.add('open', 'show');
    console.log('funcShow');
 }

const cardDeck = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
 for(var i=0;i<cardDeck.length;i++){
     cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', matchCheck);
    }

let funcRemove = function (p1,p2){

        setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);    
        p1.classList.remove('open', 'show');
        p2.target.classList.remove('open', 'show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is an asynchronous function which means that it is executed in parallel. You need to put the code that you want to run after the 1000ms delay inside of the function in `setTimeout`. For example:

```
console.log("Print #1");
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Print me after 1000ms");
}, 1000);
console.log("Print #2");
```

`"Print 2"` will print right after `"Print 1"` while the `"Print me after 1000ms"` will be printed later.

Furthermore, you can't simply return inside of `setTimeout`. Whatever you put inside of `setTimeout` is part of a callback function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function.

To make use of callbacks and `setTimeout` correctly in your case, here's what you want to do:

```
let funcRemove = function (p1,p2, callback){
    p1.classList.remove('open', 'show');
    p2.target.classList.remove('open', 'show');
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);    
}
```

In `matchCheck`:

```
let matchCheck = function(evtObj){
funcShow(evtObj);  
console.log(turnCheck);
   if(turnCheck===1){
      setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
      if(evtObj.target.innerHTML===cardChecker){
          evtObj.target.classList.add('match');
          prevCard.classList.add('match');
      }
      else{
          alert('No match');
      }
      funcRemove(prevCard, evtObj, function() {
          // this part is executed 1000ms later
          turnCheck = 0;
          cardChecker = '';
          prevCard = '';
          moves++;
          moveElem.innerHTML = moves;
      })

      return;
   }
   prevCard = evtObj.target;
   cardChecker = evtObj.target.innerHTML;
   turnCheck++;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to delay is the execution of funcRemove itself, specifically 
    'p1.classList.remove('open', 'show');
    p2.target.classList.remove('open', 'show');'     I want these classes to be removed after the alert fires and the alert dialog box is closed. Does that make sense?

Comment: `alert` is synchronous. It will pause the rest of the code and wait until you press "ok" to execute the rest of your code. If that's what you need,  you just need to move `funcRemove` inside the `else` statement so that it only runs after the alert.